# Looping a CASE WHEN and REPLACE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Apologies for the multiple basic questions - I am very new to SQL and still trying to work things out.

I would like to insert records from my staging table to another table in my database, both removing the double quotes in the source file with a 'replace' function and converting the data from nvarchar (staging table) to datetime2. I can't quite work out how to do this: if I loop the 'case when' within 'replace', as below, then SQL doesn't recognise my data and nulls it out:

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE (REPLACE([Column1], '"', '')) = 1
    THEN CONVERT(datetime2, Column1, 103) 
                    ELSE null END
```

However if I loop my 'replace' within my 'case when', as below, SQL gives me an error message saying that it is unable to convert nvarchar into datetime2:

```
LTRIM(REPLACE([Column1], '"', '')
    ,CASE WHEN ISDATE(Column1) = 1 THEN CONVERT(datetime2, Column1, 103) 
                    ELSE null END
```

What order / syntax do I need to be using to achieve this? An example of the data field would be:
"16/10/2017"

It uploads to my staging table as nvarchar
"16/10/2017"

and I would like to move it into my table2 as datetime2:
16/10/2017

Comment: Can you post up some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Are you able to upload the data in a less ambiguous format such as `yyyymmdd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `isdate()`, use `try_convert()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, LTRIM(REPLACE([Column1], '"', ''), 103)
```

I think your confusion is that you need to do the string manipulation *before* the conversion.  To do this, the string manipulation needs to be an argument to the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, that is the logic I require, just not sure how to syntax it - unfortunately this still gives me 'null' back as values.

Comment: Sorry - apologies for my earlier comment - this has worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. The problem is, `convert` needs value without `" "`, and hence your convert was failing.

Just try this :

```
select
CASE WHEN ISDATE (REPLACE([Column1], '"', '')) = 1
     THEN CONVERT(datetime2, (REPLACE([Column1], '"', '')), 103) 
     ELSE null END
from #tbl
```

more details : [cast and convert doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I still get the following error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @Sam109 : put up some sample data. Because in my sample data, this code is working.